# How to do join in Opensearch 2.3 with SQL

Tags: amazon-opensearch

This is driving me crazy. I am using Opensearch 2.3 (on a AWS managed domain).
I have 2 indices which looks something like this:

```
orders
.userId

sessions
.userId
```

And I want to do the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders JOIN sessions ON orders.userId = sessions.userId
```

but that gives me

```
Index type [orders AS orders_0] does not exist
```

And I read somewhere that I need to alias index if doing joins, so I try this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders o JOIN sessions s ON o.userId = s.userId
```

but that gives me

```
Index type [orders AS o] does not exist
```

I don't know what else to try.

(Running `SELECT * FROM orders` gives rows and the same goes for `SELECT * FROM sessions`. So the indices do exists.)